# Unable to mock enum static method with null parameter

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock a static method of enum which has null value like below

```
 try (MockedStatic<SomEnum> e = Mockito.mockStatic(SomEnum.class)) {
            e.when(() -> SomEnum.methodWhichAcceptingNullParam(any())).thenReturn(somValue);
        }
```

here any() is not working... i am not sure I am passing null parameter inside method

```
methodWhichAcceptingNullParam
```

I have tried both any and isNull.The fact is SomEnum.methodWhichAcceptingNullParam is always get called however it should not because I provided a mocked value already

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code called with a null or not-null object? This information is missing (at least for me).

Assuming you are calling SomeEnum.methodWhichAcceptingNullParam(**null**), then you need to use

> ArgumentMatchers.isNull()

instead of any().

Comment: I have tried both any and isNull.The fact is SomEnum.methodWhichAcceptingNullParam is always get called however it should not because I provided a mocked value already

Comment: Are you calling the actual method inside the curly brackets?
The mock is only valid within them.  
P.S. you should add some more context to your question or post a larger part of the unit test scenario.